# Lib Poco: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, poco-libraries, ubuntu-16.04

I get following error when linking a cmake project to poco libraries:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libPocoUtil.so.60: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN4Poco4JSON6Object3setERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_7Dynamic3VarE'
/usr/local/lib/libPocoJSON.so.60: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What I have done:
From github I built the latest developer Version 1.7.3

```
git clone https://github.com/pocoproject/poco.git
cd poco
mkdir cmake_build
cd cmake_build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

My project has following in its CMakeLists.txt file:

```
...
find_package(Poco REQUIRED Foundation Net Util JSON XML JSON)
...
target_link_libraries( ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}  ${Poco_LIBRARIES} )
```

Inspecting the library gives me following information:

```
ldd -v /usr/local/lib/libPocoJSON.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff52ffc000)
    libPocoFoundation.so.60 => /usr/local/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.60 (0x00007fb48aafc000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb48a77a000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb48a563000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb48a19a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb489f7d000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb489d78000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fb489b70000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb489867000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005619396e6000)

    Version information:
    /usr/local/lib/libPocoJSON.so:
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.20) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.11) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.9) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.21) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    /usr/local/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.60:
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libdl.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
        librt.so.1 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.15) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.11) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.7) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.20) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.11) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.9) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.21) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.15) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_4.2.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.18) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1:
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

In some other projects when I got the 'DSO missing' error I put -lm and -lstdc++ to the linked libraries.
So I tried in this case:

```
target_link_libraries( ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}  ${Poco_LIBRARIES} -lm -lstdc++ -lpthread )
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 2):

What does you command line look like?

Note that order of libraries matters, this is how libraries should be linked:

```
-lPocoUtil -lPocoXML -lPocoJSON -lPocoNet -lPocoFoundation
```

Comment: ${Poco_LIBRARIES} equals "Poco::FoundationPoco::NetPoco::UtilPoco::JSONPoco::XML".

Comment: Did you try to reorder them as I suggested above?

Comment: Yes I tried but got other Linker errors like this one:
     (.rodata._ZTVN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE[_ZTVN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE]+0x50): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl::toString[abi:cxx11]() const'

My personal solution was to use clang as compiler: 

     CXX='clang++' cmake ..

But for the records, your hint could be the solution.

Comment: that looks like you're still mixing std libs - your project and poco are not linked with same std library